# open dompdf in new tab taken data from given page

Tags: php, css, dompdf

I know that there are at least two other similar questions, but they do not help me.

I have textarea with tinymce where user writes his text. Then there is a button "PDF" that should create pdf and open it in new tab. The content of pdf is the content in tinymce.

When user click on button, the form is submitted to index.php action. Then index.php gathers information from $_POST variable and creates pdf.

I cannot get it to open in new tab as a normal link. 
I tried it in different ways.

1) I can open PDF in the same tab, but this is not what I need. This line opens my pdf on the same tab:

```
$dompdf->stream('document.pdf',array('Attachment'=>0));
```

2) I can open it in new window, but then browser warns that this is pop-up. Client doesn't want it. Also another problem with this is that pdf is stored on server. I do not want it (pop-up warning is more important).  Here is my code:

```
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents('document.pdf', $output); //save pdf on server

//opens generated pdf in new window, but this creates warning for popup
echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
window.open("http://modeles-de-lettres.org/test/saved_pdf.pdf", "_blank"); 
</script>';
```

I have read those:

1) [Open PDF in a new tab using dompdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113562/open-pdf-in-a-new-tab-using-dompdf)

This suggests: "As far as opening in a new tab. That depends on how you are generating the PDF. But the simplest way it to provide a link with a target attribute." I think this means that I have

```
<a href="my.pdf" target="blank"
```

or

```
<a href="my.php" target="blank"
```

But this does not work for me, because I should POST my form to get data from pdf.

2) [generate the pdf on newtab in dompdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419535/generate-the-pdf-on-newtab-in-dompdf)

This is something that I have implemented before (I did it without sessions), but it creats warning about popups.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do the following:

```
 <button type="submit" formtarget="_blank">Submit to a new window</button>
```

formtarget="_blank" attribute will open new tab.

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the order in which you're doing things. You should be opening the new window from a user event, like clicking a button. If a script on a page load event tries to open a window, the browser will presume it's an unwanted popup, since the user hasn't done anything besides navigating to the page.

What could work for you, is adding a `target="somewhere_new"` attribute to your `form` tag. This way, the browser would open a new tab since there's no frame/iframe with a `name="somewhere_new"` attribute, and you wouldn't have to do anything special in the server side, just process the data as you did before using `$dompdf->stream('document.pdf',array('Attachment'=>0));` at the end

Comment: FYI, the target doesn't need to be a name. You can also use the "_blank" keyword.

Comment: @BrianS this way the browser would reuse the new tab if a user were to submit the same form twice, which is usually wanted. I should've been more clear. Sorry!

Comment: Agreed, but wanted to make sure that info was included. I do something similar, but in my case I *don't* want to reuse the window.